# Testing rails partial views standalone

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, tdd, view

I'm using Test/Unit with a standard **rails 2.1** project. I would like to be able to test Partial Views in isolation from any particular controller / action.

It seemed as though [ZenTest's Test::Rails::ViewTestCase](http://zentest.rubyforge.org/) would help, but I couldn't get it working, similarly with view_test http://www.continuousthinking.com/tags/view_test

Most of the stuff Google turns up seems quite out of date, so I'm guessing doesn't really work with Rails 2.1

Any help with this much appreciated.

Thanks,
Roland

Comment: but, how can one pass in an object to the partial?

Answer (score 6):

We're using [RSpec](http://rspec.info) in our Rails 2.1 project, and we can do this sort of thing:

```
describe "/posts/_form" do
  before do
    render :partial => "posts/form"
  end
  it "says hello" do
    response.should match(/hello/i)
  end
  it "renders a form" do
    response.should have_tag("form")
  end
end
```

However I don't know how much of that you can do with the vanilla Rails testing apparatus.

Comment: yup - unfortunately I have too many test/unit tests to switch over to rspec for this project - although I've moved to rspec in current apps partially because it seems to support this fined-grained testing

Comment: What directory are you doing this in?

Answer (score 1):

Found this which may be relevant:

http://broadcast.oreilly.com/2008/10/testing-rails-partials.html

Comment: The link to O'Reilly is broken

Answer (score -3):

Testing a view without the controller code is a dangerous thing.  Your tests might pass but your application might throw an error.  Always test against real life situations not artificial ones.

Comment: > Your tests might pass but your application might throw an error.

This is always true.

I think you maybe missing what I am trying to achieve here. View testing is a small part of an overall testing strategy

Comment: You can look at the standalone view tests as unit tests. You still need functional and/or integration tests, but you can quickly test a bunch of edge cases with unit tests.